# AddDays() to a DateTime stored in UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

In C#, MVC 5, how can I perform the `AddDays()` function on a `DateTime` stored in `UTC`?

Here is my current code:

```
DateTime testDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
testDateTime.AddDays(1);
```

The `testDateTime` does not change.

I have also tried this:

```
DateTime testDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime testDateTimeKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(testDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
testDateTimeKind.AddDays(1);
```

The `testDateTimeKind` does not change.

How can I perform the `AddDays()` function on a `DateTime` stored in `UTC`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AddDays` returns a new `DateTime`, so you need to assign the returned value back to your variable, like so:

```
DateTime testDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
testDateTime = testDateTime.AddDays(1);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DBSUYM31222)